# On a canonical morphism from $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{X,p} \rightarrow X$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be a scheme. I am doing an exercise: Let $p \in X$.
Describe a canonical (choice-free) morphism from \operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O} \rightarrow X$, with
hint that says to make sure that the morphism is independent of choice.

This is what I thought:
Given any $y \in \Gamma (X, \mathcal{O}_X)$, we have image of $y$ in $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$, $y_p = [(y, X)]_p$, and this defines a ring homomorphism from $\Gamma (X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ to $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$. By the correspondence, this gives a morphism of schemes $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{X,p} \rightarrow X$.

I thought this was right, but I haven't done anything to make sure it is independent of choice. I just don't see what I am missing... I would appreciate any assistance!

PS I denoted $[(f, U)]_p \in \mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ to denote the element of stalk at $p$, given by
$f \in \Gamma(U, \mathcal{O}_X)$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not right. The adjunction between spec and global sections goes the other way:

$$\hom(X, \text{spec}(A)) = \hom(A, \Gamma(X, \mathcal O_X)).$$

What you should do is this: Choose an open affine $U = \text{spec}(A)$ containing $p$. Then there is a map $\Gamma(U, \mathcal O_X) \to \mathcal O_{X, p}$, hence a map $\text{spec } {\mathcal O_{X,p}} \to U.$ Composing with the inclusion $U \to X$, we get a morphism  $\text{spec } {\mathcal O_{X,p}} \to X$. Show that this morphism is independent of the choice of $U$.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same probem from Vakil's notes:

> 7.3.L. EXERCISE.
> (a) Suppose p is a point of a scheme X. Describe a canonical (choice-free) morphism
> Spec $O_{X,p} \to X$. (Hint: do this for affine X first. But then for general X be sure to
> show that your morphism is independent of choice.)

Besides the accepted answer by Bruno, there are other answers in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173746/morphism-from-a-local-ring-of-a-scheme-to-the-scheme). I would like to still add more details with a context from Vakil's notes, and hope this helps me to understand their answers. To construct the morphism, we choose an affine open neighborhood $U=\text{Spec}(A)$ of $p$. Denoting $\mathcal{p}\subset A$ the prime ideal of $A$ corresponding to $p$, we get the morphism of spectra from the localization $A\to A_\mathcal{p}=O_{X, p}$, and compose with the open embedding $U\to X$ to obtain the morphism of schemes:

$$\text{Spec}(O_{X, p})\to \text{Spec}(A) \to X.$$

To show this construction is independent of the choice of the open affine $U$, we choose another open affine neighborhood $V=\text{Spec}(B)$, to obtain

$$\text{Spec}(O_{X, p})\to \text{Spec}(B) \to X.$$

We can find a third open affine neighborhood $W=\text{Spec}(R)\subset U\cap V$, such that the same construction yields a third morphism

$$\text{Spec}(O_{X, p})\to \text{Spec}(R) \to X.$$

If we can show that the first two morphisms through $U$ and $V$ are equal to this third morphism through $W$, then we're done: any two morphisms constructed like this are equal (to a common third morphism factoring through a finer open affine).

To this end first note that the stalk $O_{X, p}$ is a colimit, hence the following diagram commutes:

[image: co-cone of the stalk as a colimit]

Or in other words the localization $A\to A_\mathcal{p}$ factors through

$$A\to R\to A_\mathcal{p},$$

which shows that the constructed morphism $\text{Spec}(O_{X, p})\to\text{Spec}(A)\to X$ factors through

$$\text{Spec}(O_{X, p})\to \text{Spec}(R)\to \text{Spec}(A)\to X.$$

Since open embeddings are unique: if $W\subset X$ is an open set of a scheme $X$, equipped with the unique open subscheme structure restricted from $O_X\to O_X|_U$, the embedding morphism $j: W\to X$ is uniquely determined (by the restriction). So the composition of open embeddings

$$W\to U\to X$$

which is still an open embedding, must be equal to the open embedding $W\to X$. Or in other words, $\text{Spec}(R)\to X$ factors through

$$\text{Spec}(R)\to\text{Spec}(A)\to X.$$

Now the two morphisms: $\text{Spec}(O_{X, p})\to \text{Spec}(A)\to X$ and $\text{Spec}(O_{X, p})\to \text{Spec}(R)\to X$ are both equal to the following compositions:

$$\text{Spec}(O_{X, p})\to \text{Spec}(R)\to \text{Spec}(A)\to X$$

and hence are equal.